# a Python2 to Python3 print fixer in perl

Tags: python, parsing, regex, perl

Sometimes, I'm reviewing old questions written in Python2, with no parenthesis around `print` statements. Or I'm changing one of my older codes, also without parenthesis around print statements.

It annoys me to do this manually, so I decided to write a little perl script to change it for me, however it looks rather ugly. And I think I'm missing some obvious regex to do this?

I don't yet write to another file, but just print to the commandline.

*Note that I'm making the assumption that lines that print and are net yet ended, end with `\`*

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @filenames = @ARGV;

foreach my $filename (@filenames){
    my $print_ended = 0;
    my $concat_print = qw{};
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!";

    while (my $line = <$fh>) {

        chomp $line;
        if ($print_ended) {
            $concat_print .= $line;
            $print_ended = $line =~ /\\$/;

            if (! $print_ended) {
                (my $newline = $concat_print) =~ s/print /print(/;
                 print $newline . ")\n";
                 $concat_print = qw{};
            }            
        }        
        elsif ($line =~ /print /) {
            if ($line =~ /\\$/) {
                $print_ended = 1;    
                $concat_print .= $line . "\n";     
            }
            else {
                (my $newline = $line) =~ s/print /print(/;
                print $newline . ")\n";
            }
        }
        else {
            print $line . "\n";            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've made great progress! Glad to see feedback applied. :)

Comment: Could you add an example input file please?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155547/extended-stable-marriage-challenge/ What I used as an example.

Comment: Do you know about the program `2to3` that ships with python3?

Comment: @AustinHastings Nope, I did not. :) However the intention was to learn perl anyway, so no time was wasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\h` matches horizontal white spaces

`/x` modifier instructs regex to ignore white spaces (readability)

`/m` modifier instructs `^` `$` anchors to match begin/end of line, instead of string!

```
local $/; # read all text at once

while (my $line = <>) {
    $line =~ s/print \s+ (.+? (?: [^\\]\h*$ ) )/print($1)/xgsm;
    print $line;
}
```