# Extending the extended Stable Marriage Problem using a Python class

Tags: python, algorithm, object-oriented, python-3.x, complexity

As soon as I saw this [open source paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/complexity/2018/7409397/), I thought that the best way to replicate their code would be using a `python class`. After having replicated and extended the paper [arxiv link here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.09226) entirely using a `class`, I saw this question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/155547/extended-stable-marriage-challenge) that uses loops.

I still think that when one sees the Stable Marriage Problem, an agent like solution comes to mind. I would like to ask the community whether my implementation is sound and pythonic.

The central point is a `Persons class` as per below. The idea is that all functionality: sending messages, receiving messages, maintaining ranking of other group preferences, storing partner, matching and divorcing is a single agent class.

Then, other code [GitHub/BAFurtado/HISMP/main.py](https://github.com/BAFurtado/HISMP/blob/parallel_testing/main.py) calls the class, generates the agents and applies the conditions.

The biggest advantage, I see, is the flexibility to adapt and change the class. Hence, I extended the instability problem with the possibility that any of the agents (belonging to either group: Male or Female) could actually be active messengers. I also included a `self.j` signal that informs me whether a given agent has successfully messaged all the members of the other group.

Would gladly listen to your opinions and suggestions.

EDITED: Answering the comment below, I include the `main` code which calls the class, generates groups and makes one run, below the Persons class.

```
""" Main class of the agents.
    Either Males or Females
    Already prepared to be either ACTIVE or PASSIVE agents (see accompanying paper at arXiv)
    """

import numpy as np


class Person:

    def __init__(self, name, active):
        self.id = name
        self.j = 0
        self.my_ranking = None
        self.my_partner = None
        self.my_energy = None
        self.status = active
        self.messaged = False

    def ranking(self, other_group):
        group = other_group.copy()
        np.random.shuffle(group)
        self.my_ranking = group

    def match(self, candidate):
        self.my_partner = candidate

    def divorce(self):
        self.my_partner = None

    def send_msg(self):
        if self.status == True:
            if self.my_partner == None:
                for i in range(self.j, len(self.my_ranking)):
                    result = self.my_ranking[self.j].receive_msg(self)
                    self.j += 1
                    if self.j == len(self.my_ranking):
                        self.messaged = True
                    if result == '+':
                        break

    def receive_msg(self, candidate):
        if self.my_partner is None:
            self.match(candidate)
            candidate.match(self)
            return '+'
        elif [i.id for i in self.my_ranking].index(candidate.id) < \
                [i.id for i in self.my_ranking].index(self.my_partner.id):
            self.my_partner.divorce()
            self.match(candidate)
            candidate.match(self)
            return '+'
        else:
            return '-'

    def energy(self):
        if self.my_partner is not None:
            self.my_energy = [i.id for i in self.my_ranking].index(self.my_partner.id) + 1
            return self.my_energy
        else:
            self.my_energy = len(self.my_ranking) + 1
            return self.my_energy


class Male(Person):
    pass


class Female(Person):
    pass
```

And here the `main` code:

```
""" Actual running of each repetition """

import numpy as np

from persons import Male, Female


def main(males, females):
    # Running algorithm
    # Shuffle
    np.random.shuffle(males)
    np.random.shuffle(females)
    # Personal Ranking
    [i.ranking(females) for i in males]
    [i.ranking(males) for i in females]

    singles = (max(0, len(males) - len(females)), max(0, len(females) - len(males)))
    # Messaging service
    # All active people have sent messages to everyone on the other group
    current = sum([1 for each in [males, females] for x in each if x.my_partner == None])
    not_msg = sum([1 for each in [males, females] for x in each if (x.status == True) and (x.my_partner == None)
                   and (x.messaged == False)])
    print('M, F theoretical singles: ', singles)
    print('All currently single: ', current)
    print('Not messaged: ', not_msg)

    while not_msg > 0:
        [x.send_msg() for x in males]
        [x.send_msg() for x in females]
        current = sum([1 for each in [males, females] for x in each if x.my_partner == None])
        not_msg = sum([1 for each in [males, females] for x in each if (x.status == True)
                       and (x.my_partner == None)
                       and (x.messaged == False)])
        print('Still single: ', current)
        print('Not messaged: ', not_msg)
        print('')

    return males, females


def gen_groups(group1, group2, alpha, beta=1):
    # Generate groups with a percentage (alpha) of active status (actively sends messages)
    m1, f1 = [], []
    for i in range(group1):
        m1.append(Male(i, np.random.choice([True, False], p=[beta, 1 - beta])))
    for j in range(group2):
        f1.append(Female(j, np.random.choice([True, False], p=[alpha, 1 - alpha])))
    return m1, f1


def calculate_energy(gr1, gr2, pp, homme, femme):
    res_f = np.mean([femme[i].energy() for i in range(len(femme))])
    res_m = np.mean([homme[i].energy() for i in range(len(homme))])
    with open('saved-data/energy.csv', 'a') as fl:
        fl.write('{};{};{};{};{}'.format(gr1, gr2, pp, res_m, res_f))
    return res_m, res_f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g1 = 1000
    g2 = 1000
    p = 1
    m, f = gen_groups(g1, g2, p)
    m, f = main(m, f)
    # 3. Print Energy
print('Final mean energy males: {}, females: {}'.format(calculate_energy(g1, g2, p, m, f)))
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You set a precedence that your names are poorly chosen, and don't mean what you've selected. And so they make your code hard to read.

   Pick one `id` or `name`. Looking at your code `id`/`name` is an int, and so why would you ever call it name?

   `status` is a bool (and also called `active`), but a persons status can be a wide verity of things. Is it relationship-status - Single, married, looking? But that's three states, and you've used a bool...

   `my_partner` has the useless prefix `my_`. And makes your code a little harder to read at times:

   ```
   self.my_partner.my_partner
   # vs
   self.partner.partner
   ```

   You have one function called `match` and another `divorce`. Where are `unmatch` and `marry`?

   All this piles up to make me think 'is anything named correctly?' Which means I now no-longer trust your code and have to find the definition and usage of everything in your function to build that trust again.
2. Your class `Person` should change:

   1. Rename all your functions and variables so they make sense and actually relate to each other and the task they're performing.
   2. Move the `messaged`, `my_ranking` and `j` all out of `Person`. They're about the persons candidates, and so should go in their own class.
   3. You should make a function `_ranking` that finds the index of the target passed to it from the candidates. This is as you've used the same code multiple times.
   4. `match` is a two-way relationship, but you've only defined it one way. Either get rid of the function and use `partner` directly or make it two way. Same with `divorce`.
   5. You should change `send_msg` to use guard statements so you don't get lots of indentation.
   6. Changing `receive_msg`'s name to `attempt_match` it makes sense to return a boolean on if the match was successful or not. Which is far better than `+` and `-`.
   7. Remove the `ranking` function from `Person`. It makes your code harder to test and doesn't make much sense to me to have it in the class.
3. Add a `Candidates` class, this should be a standard iterable, whilst exhibiting a value `queue` that should be an iterator. This iterator should contain the code regarding `messaged`.
4. You should keep the `np.random.shuffle` and the `Person.ranking` code in the `gen_groups` function. As they're *generating the groups*.
5. You should move a lot of your `main` code into reusable functions.
6. Don't use comprehensions for side effects. If you need to loop over something and call a function use a `for` loop.
7. Most of your comprehensions are quite hard to read.

```
class Candidates:
    def __init__(self, candidates):
        self._candidates = candidates
        self.messaged = False
        self.queue = self._build_queue()

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._candidates)

    def _build_queue(self):
        end = len(self.candidates)
        for i, candidate in enumerate(self):
            if i == end:
                self.messaged = True
            yield candidate


class Person:
    def __init__(self, id_, active):
        self.id = id_
        self.active = active
        self.partner = None
        self.candidates = None

    def _ranking(self, target):
        return [c.id for c in self.candidates].index(target)

    def match(self, partner):
        self.partner = partner
        partner.partner = self

    def unmatch(self):
        self.partner.partner = None
        self.partner = None

    def initiate_match_attempts(self):
        if not self.status or self.partner is not None:
            return

        for candidate in self.candidates.queue:
            if candidate.attempt_match(self):
                break

    def attempt_match(self, candidate):
        if self.partner is None:
            self.match(candidate)
            return True

        if self._ranking(candidate.id) >= self._ranking(self.partner.id):
            return False

        self.unmatch()
        self.match(candidate)
        return True

    def energy(self):
        if self.partner is not None:
            return self._ranking(self.partner.id) + 1
        else:
            return len(self.candidates) + 1
```

```
import numpy as np

from persons import Candidates, Person


def join(males, females):
    yield from males
    yield from females


def find_solo(males, females):
    return [
        person
        for persion in join(males, females)
        if person.partner is None
    ]


def find_not_messaged(males, females):
    return [
        person
        for person in join(males, females)
        if person.active
        and person.partner is None
        and not person.candidates.messaged
    ]


def main(males, females):
    delta = len(males) - len(females)
    if delta >= 0:
        singles = delta, 0
    else:
        singles = 0, abs(delta)

    current = len(find_solo(males, females))
    not_msg = len(find_not_messaged(males, females))

    print('M, F theoretical singles: ', singles)
    print('All currently single: ', current)
    print('Not messaged: ', not_msg)

    while not_msg:
        for person in join(males, females):
            person.initiate_match_attempts()

        current = len(find_solo(males, females))
        not_msg = len(find_not_messaged(males, females))
        print('Still single: ', current)
        print('Not messaged: ', not_msg)
        print('')
    return males, females


def randomize_candidates(sample):
    sample = sample.copy()
    np.random.shuffle(sample)
    return Candidates(sample)


def gen_groups(group1, group2, alpha, beta=1):
    males = [
        Person(i, np.random.choice([True, False], p=[beta, 1 - beta]))
        for i in range(group1)
    ]
    females = [
        Person(i, np.random.choice([True, False], p=[alpha, 1 - alpha]))
        for i in range(group2)
    ]

    np.random.shuffle(males)
    np.random.shuffle(females)

    for male in males:
        male.candidates = randomize_candidates(females)

    for female in females:
        female.candidates = randomize_candidates(males)

    return males, females


def calculate_energy(gr1, gr2, pp, homme, femme):
    res_f = np.mean([femme[i].energy() for i in range(len(femme))])
    res_m = np.mean([homme[i].energy() for i in range(len(homme))])
    with open('saved-data/energy.csv', 'a') as fl:
        fl.write('{};{};{};{};{}'.format(gr1, gr2, pp, res_m, res_f))
    return res_m, res_f


if __name__ == '__main__':
    g1 = 1000
    g2 = 1000
    p = 1
    m, f = gen_groups(g1, g2, p)
    m, f = main(m, f)
    # 3. Print Energy
print('Final mean energy males: {}, females: {}'.format(calculate_energy(g1, g2, p, m, f)))
```

Comment: There is typo in `find_solo` function, an extra i. Also, it should be 'active', instead of status in `initiate_match_attempts`. Running was about  the same time (4.79-08). All in all, the suggestions make good sense. I had never used `yield` and having a candidates `class` and not keeping the whole other group within each object is also nice. However, I was not able to replicate my output (maybe a bug on my part?). And that I think is relevant. The script never stopped for the case with groups sized 1, 999. Couldn't understand why. Anyway, appreciate all the lessons learned. Thanks.